# Two-step residualization in fuzzy RD

Tags: causality

I'm adopting a two-step residualization approach in fuzzy RD, should my first stage also include a polynomial of running variable (age)?

Comment: Very vague, explain what these acronyms are with context.

Comment: RD: regression design. But still too vague.

Comment: Say I have a treatment variable retirement, an instrument legal retirement age, and an outcome variable health. I want to examine the effect of retirement on health using a fuzzy regression discontinuity approach. I want to include covariates (e.g.gender) by taking a two-step residualization appraoch described in Lee and Lemieux (2010). But I am not sure whether I should regress health on covariates as well as age polynomials in the first stage.